# How to georeference PNG images using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, photos

How can I georeference png images using QGIS, running on OSX?

I've looked at `ExifTool`, and the plugins `GeoTag and Import Photos` + `Photo2Shape`. These tools (and other answers) as far as I can tell all use georeferenced images or images with EXIF data. I would like to load the png somewhere, and drag it around on a basemap from OpenStreeMap to position it where it should be. I know the general location, and just need to position it.

(I think I know the projection, but will find out if that is the case. The images are of an area ~500m x 200m so the projection variation will hopefully not matter hugely if I am incorrect).

Comment: Are you talking about aerial photos here?

Comment: no, they are maps but in `png` format

Comment: Can you post a sample image?

Comment: I agree, my question is a duplicate. Wondering if there is a way to make the other question a little easier to find? I did try many search terms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are most likely looking for the QGIS Georeferencer Plugin (and toolbar).  There is a good tutorial on using it called [Tutorial: Georeferencing Topo Sheets, Topo Maps, Satellite Image or Scanned Maps in QGIS](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html)